# Apache tomcat 9.0 error while configuring with eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have installed apache tomcat version 9.0 and while configuring it on eclipse neon i am getting following error:-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Digester
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.createStartDigester(Catalina.java:272)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:630)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)

Any idea what is the solution?
```

Comment: It tells you that class "org/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Digester" was not found. You might want to explain what you did and where it went wrong.

Comment: i have written a django project in eclipse using pydev and while running the project i got tomcat error.i have added catalina and tomcat-util jars in server classpath variables. @Stefan